# Is there an algebraic proof of the infinitude of primes?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, prime-numbers

It is well-known that there exists a (justly celebrated) topological proof of the infinitude of primes (Hillel Fürstenburg, 1955). Does there also exist an algebraic proof?

Comment: I will refrain from opening up the can of worms about the  "topological" proof, but there's an algebraic proof due to Larry Washington (and perhaps others before him). A semi-local Dedekind domain is PID (weak approx.), and integral closure of semi-local Dedekind domain in finite sep'ble ext'n of its fraction field is semi-local (only finitely many primes upstairs over a given one downstairs), hence PID. So existence of a number field with class number $> 1$ (e.g., $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$) implies $\mathbf{Z}$ is *not* semi-local. QED (This is not circular...)

Comment: Yes, see any book on elementary number theory (eg : Hardy and Wright).  But this question is not appropriate for MO, which is dedicated to research-level mathematics.  The FAQ lists a number of sites that are more appropriate for elementary questions.

Comment: Wow BCnrd!  Aside from the sheer joy of attacking an ant with a bazooka, is there any larger lesson in that proof?

Comment: let $p_1,\ldots,p_N$ be a complete list of primes. Since no $p_i$ divided $p_1\cdots p_N+1$, this can't be a complete list of primes. 

Comment: Without some further clarification regarding the use of the word "algebraic", I think this question should be closed.

Comment: @BCnrd: isn't your separability hypothesis superfluous?  (If so, are you feeling okay?  Do you require any medical attention??)

Comment: I agree with Scott. 

Comment: Dear Andy: I interpreted the intent of the question as being to use methods of ring theory that are generally not specific to $\mathbf{Z}$. (I do not consider Euclid's proof to be "algebraic", but rather "arithmetic": it uses methods very specific to $\mathbf{Z}$ and its cousins.) So I didn't think of it is killing a fly with a sledgehammer, but rather as a proof which is 99% commutative algebra (coupled with exhibiting a quadratic integer ring without unique factorization). As for the proof using structure theory of Lie gps...perhaps that's a sledgehammer (but not quite an "algebraic" one).

Comment: Dear Pete:  Yes, I am feeling OK.  Don't worry, I was fully aware when I wrote "separable" that it was entirely unnecessary. But in view of what we're aiming to prove, I thought it best to keep the actual commutative algebra cited as basic as possible, hence the separability hypothesis. If I'd made gratuitous reference to the Krull-Akizuki theorem in my proposed argument then Andy's "bazooka" comment would have been beyond reproach. 

Comment: Dear B: Glad to hear it.  Of course it is reasonable to say "separable" since that simplifies matters as you say.  It just -- forgive me -- didn't seem like you to do so.  

Comment: Agree with Scott.  Would vote to re-open with more clarification -- BCnrd's interpretation made it a good question.

Comment: @Cam: no. BCnrd's interpretation made a good answer of a poor question.

Answer (score 6):

[I don't really know what constitutes an "algebraic proof" of infinitude of prime numbers.]

The proof that BCnrd alludes to above is described in somewhat more length on p. 5 of

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/4400primes.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400primes.pdf)

For those who have seen this argument before: I would like to actually include a citation to something written by Washington but I have not been able to find such a document.  Does anyone know of one?

It is also possible to prove more general algebraic results by Euclid-style proofs.  One such result appeared on a UGA qualifying exam in algebra some years ago:

> Show that an infinite commutative ring $R$ with finite unit group $R^{\times}$ has infinitely many maximal ideals.

As Bill Dubuque pointed out on another forum, this problem goes back at least as far as Kaplansky's *Commutative Rings* book.  He also remarked that it is no harder to prove a slight generalization: if $R$ is infinite and $\# R > \# R^{\times})$, then $R$ has infinitely many maximal ideals.

I also posted the following question on the other forum several years ago: what is an example of a ring satisfying the hypotheses of this result for which it would otherwise be difficult to see that it has infinitely many maximal ideals?

Comment: Washington's proof appears in Ribenboim's book 'The New Book of Prime Number Records'. The citation was: "1980, Washington, L. C. The infinitude of primes via commutative algebra. Unpublished manuscript."

Comment: Washington's proof also appears in Ben Chastek, Two proofs of the infinitude of primes, http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/students/reu/benChastek.pdf but Ben doesn't say where he found it. 

Comment: @Gerry: thanks. Chastek's manuscript includes a reference to a book of Ribenboim which is, I believe, an earlier version of the book mentioned in Ben Linowitz's comment above. So he probably got it there. Perhaps "unpublished manuscript" is the best citation I'm going to get.

Comment: Dear Pete, Have you contacted Larry Washington directly regarding a possible written account of his proof?

Comment: @ME: no, I haven't wanted to bother him. I suppose though that since I am now bothering other people, it may be worth sending such an email...

Comment: See [this MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2653/242) http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2653/242 for said generalizations of Euclid's proof to rings with fewer units than elements, and references to Kaplansky's version.